# Do I need to install Ant on servers that I am deploying the files to?

Tags: ant, coldfusion

I am looking into using Ant to deploying ColdFusion files to multiple servers.  I was looking at [Ant4CF](http://ant4cf.riaforge.org/) and it says that I would need to install Ant on the servers that I am deploying to in order to work.

My question is, in general, would I need to install Ant on the servers that I am deploying to?  Or is this set-up specific to Ant4CF?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how the Ant scripts work.

For example, Ant can initiate a copy to a remote machine, using [scp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html). In this case, Ant does not need to be on the remote machine, (but you can only use the Ant tasks that work using standard protocols/methods over a network).

Since Ant4CF seems to be using the [RemoteAnt](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/server_tasks.html) task, it thus needs an Ant server on the remote machine, as well as on the machine initiating the deployment.

Other deployment methods might simply use CF on the initiating machine, to call a remote webservice which then executes an entirely local Ant script on the remote server.

It all depends on how your deployment process is setup (or how you want to set it up).